# Screen flicker while fragment transition

Tags: android, animation, fragment, android-transitions

[Here is the link to recording while pressing back button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3FZWT.gif)

While i am using a animation in a fragment transaction it's working fine but i am getting a flicker of the next screen which is annoying me. I have been searching for it since 2 days no progress.

I am using this code for transition

```
public void moveToBaseSelect() {
    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right,R.anim.exit_to_left,R.anim.enter_from_left,R.anim.exit_to_right);
    ft.replace(R.id.home_frame, new BaseSelectFragment(), HomeActivity.BASE_SELECT);
    ft.addToBackStack(HomeActivity.BASE_SELECT);
    ft.commit();

}

public void moveToLogin()
{
    if(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount()>=1 && fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryAt(fragmentManager.getBackStackEntryCount()-1).getName().equals(HomeActivity.LOGIN))
        return;

    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.enter_from_right,R.anim.exit_to_left,R.anim.enter_from_left,R.anim.exit_to_right);
    ft.replace(R.id.home_frame, new LoginFragment(), HomeActivity.LOGIN);
    ft.addToBackStack(HomeActivity.LOGIN);
    ft.commit();
}
```

The anim files

enter from left

```
<set>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromXDelta="-100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0%p" />
</set>
</set>
```

Enter from right

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromXDelta="100%p"
        android:toXDelta="0%p" />
</set>
</set>
```

exit to left

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:toXDelta="-100%p" />
</set>
</set>
```

exit to right

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <translate
        android:duration="500"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:fromXDelta="0%p"
        android:toXDelta="100%p" />
</set>
</set>
```

---

I have tried a alternative that's working by using animator instead of anim and app.fragment instead of v4.fragment

But I am extremely curious to know is there any solution if i stick with the anim method

Comment: The code looks Okay. While switching Fragment are you doing any work that will block main thread ?

Comment: Can you share the code where you are calling these functions. I want to see the flow. Also mention if flicker occurs on all transitions like forward and back?

Comment: I am just calling the above functions on button click

Comment: Without looking at a bigger picture, it's hard to tell.

Comment: Are you using the support library ? If yes which version ?

Comment: I updated the support library from 27.0.2 -> 27.1.0 and I'm seeing something similar

Comment: @darnmason exact same thing here, I reverted to 27.0.2 and the flicker went away. This workaround: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49180295/support-v427-1-0-fragment-custom-animations-do-not-work-as-expected/49316479#49316479 fixed it for me without having to go back to 27.0.2.

Comment: Cheers for the link @mjp66

Comment: I have tried a alternative that's working by using animator instead of anim and app.fragment instead of v4.fragment

Answer (score 9):

Remove your <set> elements in your animation files. I just had this problem and It disappeared when I removed them.

My xml for an animation:

```
<translate xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
    android:fromXDelta="0%"
    android:toXDelta="-100%" />
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Removing the set will remove the flicker. Thanks!

Comment: Still its flicker, I changed animation file also not working

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because commit() is asynchronous and presumably some race condition causes the flickering. Solved by making transaction manager do commitNow() instead of commit()